# What is the difference between registerKeyboardAction(...) and getInputMap().put(...) + getActionMap().put(...)?

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, keystroke

What is the difference between these two methods:

```
getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
       "pressed F10"), "someAction");

getActionMap().put("someAction", new AbstractAction() {
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          //Do something
     }
});
```

and:

```
registerKeyboardAction(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Do something
    }
}, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed F10"), JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
```

Comment: besides one method being obsolete?

Comment: You mean `registerKeyboardAction` is obsolete?

Comment: Yes, it states so in the JComponent API. Not my down-vote by the way. Up-vote to nullify it as I think that yours is a valid question.

Comment: Thanks, I think the question is now answered :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels it's my downvote - questions that can be easily solved by simply _reading_ the api doc of a single method are a waste of time for everybody, even the person that asked ...

Comment: Have you tried looking at the implementation of all methods to see how they differ?

Comment: The javadoc doesn't mention examples, so this question is perfectly valid, especially since the method is not annotated with @Deprecated, but only states this in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference, but registerKeyboardAction is obsolete as stated in the javadoc.