# How do I handle several KeyStrokes in the same actionPerformed method of an Action Listener in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, keystroke, actionevent

After having understood how to handle window level key events ([How to get a Key Event in a Java Swing JFrame instance which has many JTextFields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58713715/how-to-get-a-key-event-in-a-java-swing-jframe-instance-which-has-many-jtextfield/58714615#58714615)), I would like to define a single class which can be attached via:

frame.getRootPane ().registerKeyboardAction ( ... );

The class is the included below, and it is inteded to be used in the main window and in all the subwindows. The idea is that Fx keys will display/hide subwindows individually no matter if you are in the main window or in one of the child windows (i.e., all the application will respond in the same way to Fx keystrokes). The constructor includes both the current window and the main window where all windows are included.

My problem is that I do not know how to identify which key was pressed in the method `actionPerformed`.
Any tip on how to identify which `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Fxx,0)` triggered the actionPerformed is welcomed.

```java
public class ApplicationLevelKeys implements ActionListener {

    private MainWindow mainWindow;

    public ApplicationLevelKeys(JFrame frame, MainWindow mw) {
        mainWindow = mw;
        frame.getRootPane().registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F2,0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        frame.getRootPane().registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F12,0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {

        // F12 - Display Attribute Window
        System.out.println("F12");
        if(mainWindow.propertiesWindow.isVisible()) {
            mainWindow.propertiesWindow.setVisible(false);
        } else {
            mainWindow.propertiesWindow.setVisible(true);
        }

        // F2 - Display Period Window
        System.out.println("F2");
        if(mainWindowperiodWindow.isVisible()) {
            mainWindow.periodWindow.setVisible(false);
        } else {
            mainWindow.periodWindow.setVisible(true);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: (1-) frame.getRootPane ().registerKeyboardAction ( ... ); - did you NOT read the comment that you should NOT be using that method? Also you should be using an Action, not an ActionListener. This is the problem when you just copy posted code instead of actually reading the tutorial links. By the way you can't handle multiple KeyStrokes The Key Binding is what maps the KeyStroke to the Action.

Comment: https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/communication-success/201401/8-keys-dealing-problem-people

Answer (score 2):

I just went through some projects and found an example where I used an `InputMap` and an `ActionMap` to store the KeyStrokes and their corresponding actions;

```java
private void initKeyBindings(final JComponent c)
    {
        final InputMap iMap = c.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        final ActionMap aMap = c.getActionMap();
        String key;
        key = "f1";
        iMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F1, 0), key);
        aMap.put(key, showHelpAction);

        key = "f2";
        iMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F2, 0), key);
        aMap.put(key, saveTableAction);

        key = "f5";
        iMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F5, 0), key);
        aMap.put(key, loadTableAction);

        key = "f6";
        iMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F6, 0), key);
        aMap.put(key, focusDefaultCommandsAction);

        key = "f7";
        iMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F7, 0), key);
        aMap.put(key, focusProtocolCommandsAction);

        key = "f11";
        iMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F11, 0), key);
        aMap.put(key, loadDokuFilesAction);

        key = "f12";
        iMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F12, 0), key);
        aMap.put(key, startSignalplanAction);

        key = "Ctrl+R";
        iMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_R, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), key);
        aMap.put(key, openRevisorAction);

    }
```

In your `actionPerformed()` method you could now iterate through `aMap` and compare `aMap.getKey()` to your pressed key and then fire the corresponding action/method through `aMap.getValue()`.

Comment: If I try to do that, I get the error "cannot find symbol" for the methods put in the aMap. Can you show an example of one of the methods (i.e. showHelpAction)?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting that error? And I think I was wrong about the idea of this solution. The idea is that you pass the component you want to add these bindings to (in my case it's a JMenu) as the parameter and this method does everything that needs to be done. So after calling this method on a component, F1 key will now fire the showHelpAction. Regarding your request, in showHelpAction nothing else happens apart from ```actionPerformed()``` calling another method but no further event handling is required.

Comment: I realize this isn't exactly what you asked for as this is not "handling multiple KeyStrokes in one actionPerformed method" as you requested, but it still might be an alternative that works. I guess using this variant wouldn't require you to handle different cases in a single actionPerformed but instead would require you to create an Action for every case. Sounds like cleaner code to my ears at least but it might not be what you're looking for sorry.

Comment: I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673699/what-is-the-difference-between-registerkeyboardaction-and-getinputmap-put) SO thread from 6 years ago that talks about using ```Input/Action-Map``` vs using ```registerKeyboardAction```. The latter alias the one you used seems to have been obsolete for quite a while. So maybe rewriting this code to fit the most modern method would be a good idea here.

Comment: I managed to understand it (and it is actually a good workaround which implements actions in different AbstractActions). I was getting the error because I had not fully understood the code (now I do). The problem I face with this is that I am getting a werid behaviour from the Window Manager (I am using MWM in Linux) where toggling visibility in the subwindows works until at a certain moment the focus is set to a different window. I have no clue why this is happening but I am going to use a different approach to avoid this behaviour.

Comment: It just seems that under certain conditions the focus is not transferred back to the previous window when you hide a window.

Comment: Focus and visibility can be a weird beast indeed! Sometimes it's best to not let it handle itself and instead calling ```setFocusable()``` manually on components that should or shouldn't be focusable. I feel like it's best to separate the actions in cases like these, if not for actually getting code to compile then at least for ensuring the single responsibility principle!

Comment: (1+) for using InputMap and ActionMap to do the Key Bindings. @M.E., *it is actually a good workaround which implements actions in different AbstractActions* - it is not a workaround. It is the way Actions should be used. An Action should do a single function. In your case you could create a generic Action that takes a Window as a parameter. Then you just create a new instance of the Action for each Window you want to manage.

Comment: @yur, although a bit offtopic, regarding the focus comments I found that doing setVisible(true) and invoking requestFocus() on the main window BEFORE doing setVisible(false) on the subwindows make the focus work in a consistent way. It seems that once you do setVisible(false) in the subwindow without having set focus to other JFrame the window manager/X11 environment will have a life on its own. I am not sure if that is the proper way of solving this issue but at least it creates a consistent behaviour (much better than what I had previously).

Comment: If you want to actually get rid of a Frame you shouldn't call ```setVisible(false)``` as it merely hides the window instead of actually exiting/terminating it. You should use ```dispose()```.

Comment: @yur thanks for the tip, I am aware of it. I intentionally want to toggle the visibility of the Frame. I guess that will avoid instantiating the Frame and hence will be faster. They are properties subwindows related to a main window, theuser can show/hide those subwindows to alter parameters on demand, so I thought it would be better if they are created as hidden companions of the main chart and displayed/hidden on demand.

Comment: @yur I still got weird behaviour (less than at the beginning) by hidding/showing the JDialogs (I moved them into JDialogs), so I used .dispose() and created the component again everytime is shown. This seems to work smooth in terms of focus/defocus. I still return the focus to the main window with `.setVisible(true)`  `.requestFocus()` and `.toFront()`. I am mentioning it in case someone experiences issues with the focus